# Rails force input to encode in windows-1250

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm making an app on existing database in firebird with charset windows-1250.
And im getting a lot of troubles because of this encoding, but i cant change it.

My biggest error now is when im making form for input object called notification like this:

```
 form do |f|
  panel Iconv.conv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', 'Opis zgłoszenia:'), 
    :class=> 'panel_dodaj_new' do
      f.input :opis_zgloszenia, label:false
    end
 end
```

It try to save text in utf-8, but i want it to save in windows-1250.

How to force `:opis_zgloszenia` to save in different charset than utf-8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find way to change encoding in controller.
In my create method i add:

```
@notification.opis_zgloszenia = 
Iconv.conv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', @notification.opis_zgloszenia)
```

also i need to change my update method:

```
if @notification.update(notification_params)
    @notification.opis_zgloszenia = Iconv.conv('windows-1250', 'utf-8', @notification.opis_zgloszenia)
    if @notification.save
      redirect_to request.url
    end
  end
```

Now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a more appropriate solution to this is to configure the default encoding for your whole database. That way, I would expect Rails to transparently convert the encoding between the database (windows 1250) and Rails code / web pages (UTF-8). You should be able to set this using the `encoding` setting in your `database.yml` configuration.

So something like the following should work for you:

```
development:
  adapter: fb
  database: db/development.fdb
  username: SYSDBA
  password: masterkey
  host: localhost
  encoding: windows-1250
  create: true
```

See the [Firebird adapter documentation](https://github.com/rowland/activerecord-fb-adapter) for more info.